# Android XBMC Remote with Raspberry Pi Hotspot

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, remote, openelec, android

just got a a raspberry pi. preloaded with open elec. I noticed that I could setup a hot spot.

I just wondering is at all possible to use Android XBMC Remote to connect to the open elec hotspot and use the remote.

removing the need for a network or wifi router.

Comment: By "XBMC Remote" are you referring to the android/iphone app?

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific.   am using the Android XBMC Remote that you can get through the play store. I havr updated the original text

Comment: This should be possible. Do you have a usb wifi dongle? If so start up a network, connect to it on your android device, and try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get use to the menu and the structure.  Just needed to make sure the right IPv4 was configured and all the details were correct.  You know you are doing it right when the MAC address was auto populated.

You will need to have openelec setup as a hotspot so that your phone can connect.